# QPDF in node child_process: can't find file

Tags: node.js, pdf, child-process

I'm trying to execute qpdf to merge several pdf files into one. Simply put, my code needs to execute the command from node, but it always return an error saying the pdf files couldn't be found. This is the simplest code possible (fileNames is an array of... file names):

```
command = "qpdf --empty --pages #{fileNames.join ' '} -- #{key}.pdf"
require('child_process').exec command, (err, stdout, stderr) ->
    console.log err, stdout, stderr
```

err contains

```
{ [Error: Command failed: open 1fc31c0c61f1413bb273042fb9ac47aa_1.pdf: No such file or directory] 
killed: false, code: 2, signal: null }
```

The pdf files and the node process are in the same folder and if a copy & paste the command into the terminal, everything works as expected.

The qpdf syntax is

```
qpdf --empty --pages file1.pdf file2.pdf fileN.pdf -- output.pdf
```

At first I thought it could be some problem within the qpdf itself, but when I tried another program (pdfmerge), the same error happened.

Is this something regarding the child_process execution?

Answer (score 0):

For folks looking for answers, not only make sure the file is there, make sure the file is finished when looking for it. This was my case, the child process finished but the file write didn't.

The solution I found was to stream the pdf to a file on the node side and chain the partial pdf execution so it would only call the next pdf processing when done writing the file.